# How to create a list from instances?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, instances

complete edit^^:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

walk = [100, 100]

#start: probability 1.0 at position 0.
position0 = Distribution.start(10)
plot(position.plotlists(*arena)[0], position.plotlists(*arena)[1],
     linestyle='steps')

for m in walk:
    move = Distribution.probability(m, 2)
    position1 = convolve(position1, move)

    plot(position1.plotlists(0,300)[0], position1.plotlists(0,300)[1],
         linestyle='steps')
```

I want to calculate the probaility of my robot arriving exactly 100 cm further and i do that 2 times which is done by the variable ***walk***. So as an easy case I distribute (+/- 1 from the desired goal) the probaility for the first step:

99 cm as 0.25 , 100 cm as 0.5 and 101 cm as 0.25 given out as `start = 99, values = 0.250000 0.500000 0.250000` which is saved in the variable ***move***. next loop the variables are overwritten.

this works fine. so now i need to make a tree chart and sum it up for both steps. depending on the  3 possible position for the second move, done by ***convolve***.... I should

my convolve(position,move) looks like this`c= position.append(move) result=sum_upTC(c) return result` with predefined function `sum_upTC(distributions, weights = None)`. when i execute it, python gives me the error : *line 20, in convolve
    c=a.append(b)
AttributeError: Distribution instance has no attribute 'append'*

sum_upTC takes one variable that contains the position1 (initially, `start = 0, values = 1.0000`) and the variable ***move***

after 2 loops the following probility distribution,calculated separately each loop, should be plotted:

```
start = 0, values = 1.0000

start = 99, values = 0.250000 0.500000 0.250000

start = 198, values = 0.062500 0.250000 0.37500 0.250000 0.062500
```

need the *sum_upTC* code too?

anyone can give me input (explained in an easy way^^ *newbie*) on this?
please and thx^^

---

so want i want to create is a plot that shows me the probability of my robot being at the desired position and the probability missing it and arriving at +-1 cm of the desired goal. therefore I distribute the probility of arriving with .25, .5 and .25 (-1, desired goal, +1). As I am moving multiple times the probability of arriving at that distance changes and the possibilities actually increases. in this case the first step has 3 possibilities and the second 5. (for the values look above, calculated by using a tree chart) and this should be plotted.

I will begin at the the main part.

1.define the moving distance for each step in parameter ***walk***, move 2 times 100 cm

2.create a starting point with value 100% as it is the docking station and the location is exactly known. plot it

3.loop 2 times. loop calculate the step for moving from start 100 cm away (function ***move***). the distribtuion is in the first post.  convolved and then ploted into the existing plot.

the first loop is not worth mentioning the second loop should give `start = 99, values = 0.250000 0.500000 0.250000` as coordinates and `start = 198, values =  0.250000 0.500000 0.250000` both are types of **instances**. but my function ***sum(a,b)*** takes **a** as the both instances as one parameter **b** is the weight of the distribution.

so my question is how to put the 2 instances together. obviously the standard `.extend` and `.append` dont work. i get the error mentioned above

Comment: Can you show the exact code that's giving you the error, the full traceback for the error, and explain exactly what you expect the output to be? As is, I can't tell what you're asking at all.

Comment: wrote the question anew, hope this helps^^

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example which can be executed!

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. Answers are meant to fully answer the question. Instead **edit** your question.

Comment: And please don't ask _questions_ in answers. Stack Overflow is designed as a repository of questions and answers. It is not a forum and should not be used like one.

Answer (score 0):

this should work when copied into on file.

```
from pylab import plot, show, ylim
from math import exp, ceil

class Distribution:
    def __init__(self, offset = 0, values = [1.0]):
        self.offset = offset
        self.values = values[:]

    def normalize(self):
        s = float(sum(self.values))
        if s != 0.0:
            self.values = [i / s for i in self.values]

    def value(self, index):
        index -= self.offset
        if index < 0 or index >= len(self.values):
            return 0.0
        else:
            return self.values[index]

    def plotlists(self, start = None, stop = None):
        if start == None:
            start = self.start()
        if stop == None:
            stop = self.stop()
        if start <= stop:
            indices = [i + 0.5 for i in xrange(start, stop)]
            vals = [self.value(i) for i in xrange(start, stop)]
            return (indices, vals)
        else:
            return ([], [])

    @staticmethod
    def unit_pulse(center):
        return Distribution(center, [1.0])

    @staticmethod
    def triangle(center, half_width):
        w = int(half_width)
        c = int(center)
        values = []
        for i in xrange(-w+1, 0):
            values.append(w+i)
        for i in xrange(0, w):
            values.append(w-i)
        d = Distribution(center-w+1, values)
        d.normalize()
        return d

    @staticmethod
    def sum(distributions, weights = None):
        if not weights:
            weights = [1.0 for d in distributions]

        start = min([d.start() for d in distributions])
        stop  = max([d.stop() for d in distributions])
        sum_dist = [0.0 for _ in xrange(start, stop)]
        for i in xrange(len(distributions)):
            dist = distributions[i]

            for j in xrange(len(dist.values)):
                sum_dist[dist.start()-start+j] += dist.values[j] * weights[i]
        d = Distribution(start, sum_dist)
        Distribution.normalize(d)
        return d

def move(distribution, delta):

    return Distribution(distribution.offset+delta, distribution.values) 

def convolve(a, b):
    c=a.append(b)
    result=sum(c)
    return result 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    walk = [100,100] 

    coordinates = Distribution.unit_pulse(10)
    plot(coordinates.plotlists(0,300)[0], coordinates.plotlists(0,300)[1],
         linestyle='steps')

    # Now move and plot.
    for m in walk:
        move_distribution = Distribution.triangle(m, 2)
        coordinates = convolve(coordinates, move_distribution)
        print coordinates
        plot(coordinates.plotlists(0,300)[0], coordinates.plotlists(0,300)[1],
             linestyle='steps')

    ylim(0.0, 1.1)
    show()
```

Comment: please elaborate more with some explanations... we hope to understand, not to copy paste :P